# Why is wpf combobox not being drawn, even though the visibility is set to "true"?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, visibility

I have a Combobox whose Visibility is bound to a bool Property in ViewModel. The Combobox is located inside a stackPanel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
     <ComboBox Height="50" Style="{StaticResource GameBalanceComboBox}" MinWidth="130" Margin="5 0" ItemsSource="{Binding SlotsBalances}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Visibility="{Binding IsBalanceShowVis, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibility}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectBalance}" Background="#411A10" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <ComboBox.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.5" Color="Black" Direction="270" BlurRadius="4" ShadowDepth="1"/>
        </ComboBox.Effect>
     </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

The problem is that when the event is raised (user logged in) which sets the Visibility bound value to true, the combobox is not shown, even though it's visibility is set to "Visible", BUT when I open another UserControl and then go back to the one with the Combobox, it gets drawn. The Visibility bound property gets set to true and then a boolToVis converter is used.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Below are the screenshots:

[The combobox is inside the red border (visual studio debugger)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Aoy0.png)

[Here's a screenshot from Visual Studio's Live Property Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooSWT.png)

[Here's what the Combobox actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsFwD.png)

EDIT: The UserLoggedIn event handler code:

```
public void Handle(UserLoggedIn mess)
    {
         SlotsBalances.Clear();
         SlotsBalances.AddRange(User.Instance.Balances.Where(el => (el.Type == 0) || (el.Type == 2)));
         SelectBalance = SlotsBalances.FirstOrDefault(el => (el.Type == 0));
         NotifyOfPropertyChange("IsBalanceShowVis");
    }
```

The IsBalanceShowVis property:

```
public bool IsBalanceShowVis { get { return SlotsBalances.Count > 1; } }
    private bool _isBalanceShowVis;
```

[As I mentioned earlier, this property is set to true in the event handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiqzr.png)

The GameBalanceComboBox style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="GameBalanceComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ToggleButton
                                x:Name="ToggleButton"
                                Template="{StaticResource GameBalanceToggleButtonComboBox}"
                                Focusable="false"
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                ClickMode="Press"
                                />
                    <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="ContentSite"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                Margin="5,0,24,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                Style="{x:Null}"
                                Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Margin="5,0,24,0"
                                Focusable="True"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                Visibility="Hidden"
                                IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                    <Popup
                                x:Name="Popup"
                                Placement="Bottom"
                                IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                                AllowsTransparency="True"
                                Focusable="False"
                                PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid
                                    x:Name="DropDown"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"               
                                    MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                    MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border
                                        x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                        Background="White"
                                        BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="0 0 3 3"
                                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource CouponToggleButtonBorderBrush}"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0 0 0 3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" >
                                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource GameBalanceComboBoxItem}">
                                            <!--<Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                    --><!--"#1F72AF"--><!--
                                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>-->
                                        </Style>
                                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0 0 4 4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in your VM?

Comment: Can you post the relevant view model code and the GameBalanceComboBox style markup?

Comment: @pm_2, Yes, I have. I forgot to mention this, I'm going to update the answer right now.

Comment: Are you using the stock BooleanToVisibilityConverter? In your first screenshot, the visual debugger shows an outline for your ComboBox. If it is Collapsed, it shouldn't show an outline. Can you check the live tree to see what the values are for ActualHeight and Opacity?

Comment: @Eric, Yes, I am using the stock converter. I guess it translates a boolean "false" value into a Hidden visibility and that's why the outline is shown. I checked the live tree and the ActualHeight is set to 50 (actualWidth is 130), and the opacity value is 1.

Comment: What type of collection is SlotBalances? List? Have you tried using ObservableCollection<>?

Comment: @Eric, SlotBalances is of ObservableCollection type.

Comment: I've tried recreating your scenario the best I can, but I am not getting any issues. Are you getting any binding errors in your output window? Also, do you experience the same problem if you don't use the custom style?

Comment: How many elements are present in SlotsBalances when you call NotifyOfPropertyChanged()?  Could it be that you don't have at least 2 elements?

Comment: Is your eventing mechanism running on a background thread or the UI thread?

Comment: @Eric, No, I don't get any binding errors and yes, I experience the same problem even if I don't use the style. The funny thing is, as I mentioned in the question, that if I switch to another view and then back to the view with the combobox, it does redraw itself and everything's fine. The problem occurs only if I stay in the same view, while trying to change the visibility. Also, I use Caliburn Micro's event aggregator for events, so I don't think there can be any problem with that. I have no idea what it could be. The combobox just doesn't draw itself the first time for some reason.

Comment: @pm_2, I checked it and there are 2 elements in SlotsBalances when I call the NotifyOfPropertyChanged, so it's probably not that

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the visibility change itself, because if I remove the Visibility change (so that when the view gets shown, the visibility is set to true by default), then the Combobox is shown the first time. I have the same Combobox in another view and everything works fine there. The main difference is that this Combobox is inside a StackPanel and the one that works is inside a Grid. Maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: Could that code be executing before the page is loaded?

Comment: So I solved the issue by switching stackpanel to grid and the issue disappeared. I have no idea what was wrong, but now it's solved..